# Calculating standard deviation of samples with boostrapping in R

Tags: r, statistics, statistics-bootstrap

Imagine: I have sampled 10,000 humans and measured their height in cm, and drawn the distribution as follows:

```
# Generate sample data
sampleSize = 10000
sampleData = round(rnorm(n=sampleSize, mean=175, sd=14))

# Draw histogram of sample
h = hist(sampleData, breaks=max(sampleData)-min(sampleData))

######################################################################
# Calculate the mean of the measurement
meanMeasure = mean(sampleData)
meanMeasure
abline(v=meanMeasure, col="red")

# Calculate the standard deviation of the measurement
sdMeasure = sd(sampleData)
sdMeasure
rect(
    xleft=meanMeasure-sdMeasure,
    ybottom=min(h$counts),
    xright=meanMeasure+sdMeasure,
    ytop=max(h$counts),
    col="#0000ff22"
)
```

Now I want to estimate how large the standardDeviation is for each measured body height. I thought that bootstrapping my original dataset would be a good method, i.e sampling body sizes from my original dataset with replacement.

Is this a good method?
How can I perform this analysis in R (e.g. standard deviation for each height in a bootstrap analysis with 1000 cycles)?

Comment: Maybe it could be something like this: `cycles = 1000`
`result = matrix(0, nrow = length(h$counts), ncol = cycles)`
`for (i in 1:cycles) {
 tmp = hist(sample(sampleData, replace = T, size = sampleSize), breaks = h$breaks, plot=F)
 result[,i] = tmp$counts
}`
`for (i in 1:length(h$counts)) {
 h$sdboot[i] = sd(result[i,])
}`
`plot(h)`
`polygon(x=c(rev(h$mids), h$mids), y= c(rev(h$counts+h$sdboot), h$counts-h$sdboot), col="#ff000022")`

Answer (score 2):

If you measure each individual only once there is no way of obtaining the standard deviation  "for each measured body height". Bootstrapping can only be used if you have more than one datapoint for which you want to obtain an estimate.

For obtaining the standard deviation "for each measured body height" , each body height would have to be measured more than once.

If you, however, want to obtain an bootstrapped estimate of the standard deviation of you overall sample, then the other two answers apply.

Furthermore, this question would be better suited on [crossvalidated.com](http://crossvalidated.com).

Comment: Most body heights are measured several times. For example of the 10'000 measurements 300 could be 175cm in another measurement the number of subjects with 175cm could be only 280. So between measurements there should be a variance for the number of subjects with the height 175cm. And I want to estimate that variance.

Comment: I am not talking about the different measured heights, but about the different individuals you measured. Furthermore, in your data, there is no chance to obtain what you want. You would need more precise values (e.g., 175.4 cm) to estimate this variability.

Answer (score 1):

It's entirely unnecessary to use bootstrapping for that purpose when your sample size is so large. If you wanted to know the extent of plausible variation in the standard deviation in samples of only 100 or 200 or maybe even 500 individuals, then bootstrapping would be informative. But with 10,000 individuals the bootstrap variation in the standard deviation is going to be very, very small.

Comment: As Charlie said, I thought bootstrapping is useful to generate pseudo samples. I have only measured a single sample. But I want to know how the number of individuals in certain height classes varies between Several measurements. I could also split my sample into 10 distributions with 1000 measurements each, and calculate the varience of the each hight class with an n=10. I thought bootstrapping would be a better method for "estimating the variance of the height classes between (independent) measurements".

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrapping is usually employed to calculate the variance of an estimator, in your case, the sample mean height. When you're just looking to find the variance of the heights of people, you don't need to do a bootstrap.

Why do we bootstrap? Because for our one sample we only have one sample mean. So we need many samples to get many sample means to calculate the variance of that estimator. Bootstrapping is a way to get many pseudo-samples when we only have one.

In your case, we already have many individual observations of heights, so we don't need any more---we can just calculate the variance directly based upon our "real" observations.

Comment: In my example I already measured the standard deviation of the body height in my sample. But, I want to find out the standard deviation of each height between samples. As you mentioned therefore we need pseudo samples from the original sample. For example I want to ask the question: "What is the variance of the number of subjects with the height 175cm between several independet measurements".